# How can I make a small space here between the icon and text

Tags: html, reactjs

I learn Reactjs and JavaScript and now I have this problem please advice

In this image the "Sign in" does not have a space in between like the other between the icon and text

[image]

This is the code:

```
<li style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
    <a onClick={onProfilePageClick} style={{ display: 'flex' }} role="presentation">
        <span className="icon is-medium">
            <i className="fas fa-user" />
        </span>
        <div>
            {authUser && Array.isArray(authUser.roles) && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.USER) ? 
                    <div>Dashboard</div>
            ) : (
                <div>Sign in</div>
            )}
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is the code for the `Search` menu item: that has a space between icon and text

```
        <li>
            <a onClick={onSearchPageClick} role="presentation">
                <span className="icon is-medium">
                    <i className="fas fa-search" />
                </span>{' '}
                Search
            </a>
        </li>
```

I have tried like adding space in front of the "Sign in" text but it's not read in. Please advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all the icons have almost equal space. If you want more space. You can use `margin-right:1rem;`  property on span.

**CSS:**

```
span.icon{
   margin-right:5px;
}
```

If you want inline-style in React then you can do:

```
    <span className="icon is-medium" style={{marginRight:"1rem"}}>
        <i className="fas fa-user" />
    </span>
```

Comment: If I do like this then the space between icon and text is to large. But I see I can use 0.5rem

Comment: Use: margin-right:5px; adjust the pxs as per your requirement. I think 5px is good in this case

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use `<div style={{marginLeft: “5px”}}>`
You can also try `{‘ ‘}`

Comment: The other menu items have the {‘ ‘} so I must use the same here or else it look funny